# How to configure IPython shell on macOS so that right arrow works in the same way as ctrl-f?

Tags: ipython

On macOS in a fresh virtualenv with python 3.8.16 and IPython 8.12.1, when I press the left arrow the cursor moves left as expected but the right arrow key does nothing. Ctrl-f does move the cursor to the right though.

The right arrow works ok with the console in the regular `python` but not when I start with `ipython`.

I have removed my `~/.ipython` too, the right arrow still does not work

I tried with the linux version via docker and I see the same behaviour

```
docker run -ti --entrypoint "" python:3.8.16 /bin/bash
pip install ipython
ipython
```

How can fix the right arrow key in ipython?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bug reported at https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/14051,

You can "fix" it by removing the keyboard shortcut for `auto_suggest.resume_hinting`. To do so you need to add add the following to `~/.ipython/profile_default/ipython_config.py`

```
c.TerminalInteractiveShell.shortcuts = [
    {"command": "IPython:auto_suggest.resume_hinting", "new_keys": []}
]
```

On Python 3.9+ you can use IPython 8.13.0+ and the right arrow key will work with no need to modify the `ipython_config.py`